# how can i pass variable to php after open modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I want to open modal after I click on button. But I want to display different content on the basis on which button I click.

So in html I have:

```
<h1>article1</h1>
<div class="btnComment">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Comment button 1</button>
</div>
<h1>article2</h1>
<div class="btnComment">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Comment button 2</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Comments</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php
                mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
                $selectConf = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM e_comments WHERE article='".$article."'");
                $count = 0;
                if($selectConf){
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($selectConf)) {
                        $text = $row['text'];
                        echo $text;
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So how can I know in modal which button was clicked? And how I can pass some variable throw it? I want to show comments of article. So I need to pass id of article and select all comments where is id of article same.

Comment: You'll need some javascript for that, your code currently is executed once on page load, and that's it. you should also read a bit on seperation of concerns, your view(html) is mixed with your data(mysql)

Comment: It is just a simple example to better imagination

Comment: When I need javascript how can I pass variable?

Comment: Well that's a bad example, what you want is some form of ajax to pull in information from the server and then populate the modal, or have all that info on the client already and parse it before showing the modal, alot of topions really

Comment: can someone show me some example?

Answer (score 1):

There's a direct example on the bootstrap page at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target. Here is the equivalent code for your dialog

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bs-example-modal-lg').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
            alert(button.html())
        })
    })
</script>
```

**edit** : you'd have to change the alert() part to whatever if else logic you want.